# No Values Received Inside Component Code During Error Testing in Catch Block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How can I address the issue of not obtaining any values within my component code during error testing within the catch block of my error handling mechanism?

Service Code:

```
export const fetchIdea = async (
    suggestIdeaInput: GetSuggestedIdeaParams,
    topLevelPageId: string
): Promise<SuggestedIdeaOutput> => {
    try {
        const ideaData = await graphqlApi(topLevelPageId, 'getSuggestedIdea', getSuggestedPrice, {
            suggestIdeaInput,
        });

        if (ideaData?.data.errors) {
            throw new Error(ideaData.data.errors[0]);
        }
        return ideaData?.data.data.suggestPrice;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};
```

Component Code:

```
const onFetchSuggestedIdea = async (
    suggestIdea: GetSuggestedIdea
): Promise<SuggestedIdeaOutput> => {
    try {
        return await fetchIdea(suggestIdeaInput, topLevelPageId);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in onFetchSuggestedIdea:', error);
        throw new Error(error);
    }
};
```

Comment: `catch (error) { throw error; }`?! Also when you create a `new Error` from an existing error (which there's not much point in doing in this case) the existing one should be the `cause`, not the `message`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/cause

Comment: I am not even getting error that is thrown from service in the component. When I log it in the console I am getting [Object, Object] If I stringify it then value is empty like {}

Comment: That doesn't mean you're not getting the error; `JSON.stringify(new Error("some stuff", { cause: new Error("other stuff") })) === "{}"` (because those properties aren't enumerable).

Comment: I have logged the error the came from the service inside in if condition before return error. it has the value